# How to rbind a list of rda files

Tags: r, rbind, rda

I have a list of .rda data files with names all start with say AAA, and need to rbind all of them into one dataset
I tried the following codes but it does not work

```
files <- list.files(pattern="AAA")
df <- do.call(`rbind`,lapply(files, load))
```

Comment: Are you trying to `rbind` the tables within a `.rda`?

Comment: *"it does not work"* ... how, precisely? Do you get an error? Warning? Perhaps neither but your data looks wrong?

Comment: Yes, I have 70 .rda data that I need to rbind. If I use the code provided above, the df file I got is a column of names of each .rda files